.aspx files not seeing codebehind class members (webforms)
We recently upgrade our old webforms code base to .NET Framework 4.8.
All .aspx files, .aspx.cs files and aspx.cs.designer files were properly configured.
Problem is we now have compile errors for every .aspx files saying that the name MyProperty does not exist in the current context.
Strangely the .aspx and aspx.cs and the aspx.designer.cs are not completely disconnected as I can access html controls that implement an ID attribute and runat="server" in my codebehind file just fine. It's my public properties and methods in my codebehind that I cannot access in my .aspx file (as well as nested static classes).
This may be a hint but when I launch to compile I get

Impossible to load type "Helvartis.Annuaire.Global"
Line 1 :  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Helvartis.Annuaire.Global" Language="C#" %>

And this project is a hybrid between ASP.NET MVC and webforms.

I checked if my namespaces didn't get modified
I have checked if every dependency is also targeting .NET Framework 4.8
I have compared my old git csproject file to see if there was something different going on. As well as my web.config assembly references
I have cleaned and rebuild solution.
I tried deleting a file and recreating it...
I tried removing the public from partial classes if unnecessarily duplicated.

I'm out of ideas...

You don't note how you upgraded. But to upgrade, you open the project, and simply change the .net framework from say 3.5 to 4.8 or whatever. If the project builds, then you are done. Did you do anything else other then JUST change the .net framework and try building? It not clear if you updated the project type, or JUST changed the .net framework of which is all you really need to do here.
